# C++ Unscoped Enum Type When Trying to Add Class Constructs

Tags: c++, enums

the following code is meant to add two LargeNum type class constructs and add them.

```
class LargeNum
{

private:
    NumNode* first;
    NumNode* last;

    bool isNeg;

public:

    int value;
    NumNode* next;

    //todo constructor, inital point

    //constructor
    LargeNum(int value);
    LargeNum(string value);
    //destructor
    ~LargeNum();

    //members   
    void Append(int value);
    string ToString()const;

    const LargeNum LargeNum::operator+ (const LargeNum& ln2)
    {

        LargeNum result = value + ln2.value;

        return result;

    }

    //LargeNum add(LargeNum val1, LargeNum val2);

};
```

When I try and add the two in the main.cpp then I get integral or unscoped enum type error and it references the second pointer. See below.

```
LargeNum Result_1 = L1 + L2;
```

with the error falling on l2. Thoughts?

Comment: Please show the offending code in main.cpp, and the actual compiler error output.

Comment: the offending code is the last line in the question (LargeNum Result_1 ...) the error is as follows

Comment: error C2110: '+' : cannot add two pointers
error C2512: 'LargeNum' : no appropriate default constructor available IntelliSense: expression must have class type

Comment: Something doesn't add up, gcc gives unrelated errors and VS isn't giving me the same error you're reporting. Please try posting a complete, minimal example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what is the error that you get, however, the code below compiles just fine (a simplified version of your class)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class LargeNum
{

public:

int value;

//todo constructor, inital point

//constructor
LargeNum(int value):value(value){};
LargeNum(string value){};
//destructor
~LargeNum(){};

//members   

const LargeNum operator+ (const LargeNum& ln2)
{

    LargeNum result = value + ln2.value;

    return result;

}
};

int main()
{
    LargeNum L1=4;
    LargeNum L2=5;
    LargeNum L3=L1+L2;

    cout <<L3.value;

}
```

and outputs 9 as a result. Btw, you don't need the extra `LargeNum::` qualification when declaring `operator+()`. Check if it compiles without, if not, please post the whole code (with implementation) in a single file.

Comment: Works great! Thanks mate. Just saved my C++ grade lol. Good luck with your Quantum Computing endeavors as well.